# "name 'random' is not defined" when using random.randint

Tags: python, random

I am writing a Python script that will print out a random value from a list I have written,

```
from random import randint
class_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
people_called=[]
randomized_number = random.randint(0,12)
print "debug number" + str(randomized_number)
print "The student is" + str(class_list[randomized_number])
class_list[randomized_number].append(people_called)
```

However when I run this file I get I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Code/class list.py", line 4, in <module>
    number = random.randint(0,12)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: you have imported the symbol `randint` from `random`... so you should call `randint` directly (without prefix). Alternatively, `import random` then use `random.randint`.

Comment: Listen to the error messages .. they don't lie. So find out *why* they are telling the [unexpected] truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from random import randint` imports `randint` from `random` module. That is, you can just use it as `randint`. If you would import it as `import random`, you'd have to use `random.randint` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When importing using just import random, you must call the function with random.randint().

When using from random import randint, Python lets you call the function with just randint()